# Unable to build Floodlight Controller Package Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, sdn

I am working on using [Floodlight Controller for SDN](http://www.projectfloodlight.org/download/). I used

```
ant eclipse
```

to setup the `Eclipse` files and then changed the Build Configuration as desired in the installation instructions. I am getting the following compilation error in the package `net.floodlightcontroller.util.MatchUtils`:

```
The method setMasked(MatchField<F>, Masked<F>) in the type Match.Builder is not applicable for the arguments (MatchField, Masked)
```

on lines 141 and 148.

Can somebody help me with the issue?

Operating System: `Mac OS X 10.10`

Java Version:

```
java version "1.8.0_25"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_25-b17)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.25-b02, mixed mode)
```

Comment: It works with `Java SE 1.7`. [Check Github Issue Here](https://github.com/floodlight/floodlight/issues/487)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested in the comments above, it works with `Java SE 1.7`. There is also a [Github Issue](https://github.com/floodlight/floodlight/issues/487).